# How to migrate an Angular Application that was not created with the Angular CLI to an Angular CLI project?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have developed an Angular application using tools such as **NPM** (I did not use the Angular CLI). What is the best way to migrate the project to the CLI project model? For example, I want to be able to use commands like `ng serve`.

Comment: You mean to say you developed Angular Application without Angular CLI !!!

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what do you mean developed using npm and what do you want to do in Angular CLI.

Comment: @AdritaSharma  i developed angular application without Angular CLI. now i am using "npm start" to run application. i want to convert it to Angular CLI so that i can use "ng serve"

Comment: I think you are using angular.js. right? angular cli is for angular 2+

Comment: @LibinCJacob No not angular.js. It is Angular 2+ only but I developed without CLI. now i want to convert project into CLI

Comment: you just create a new project having the same name of you existing one using angular-cli. Then replace the src file of new one with the old.

Comment: angular-ci is old one. I think you can use the latest one with the help of @angular/cli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert an Angular project to use the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/), you could follow these steps.

#### 1. Install the CLI

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

#### 2. Create a new CLI Project

```
ng new my-first-project
cd my-first-project
ng serve
```

#### 3. Copy your existing code files into the new CLI Project

#### 4. [Configure your Angular Workspace](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config)

## Differences between Angular CLI and Other Build Systems

Notes from [Migrating a project to Angular CLI build system](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/migrating-to-angular-cli/#lessons-learned)

- Angular CLI may use multiple `tsconfig.json` files (be sure to setup dependencies between files correctly)
- `ng serve` and `ng test` compile your typescript into memory rather than physical files.
- If `ng test` doesn't work and gives cryptic errors look into the `pollyfills.ts` file and start uncommenting lines.
- Consider locking `package.json` versions with exact version numbers, shrinkwrap, lockfile, or yarn. There is no joy in debugging `@types`, tsc versions and incompatible modules.
- Building with `ng build --prod` (which uses AOT compilation) is a lot more strict than the default typescript rules with `ng serve`.
- Using sass for css:

  1. When creating new project: `ng new my-first-app --style=scss`
  2. Or modify `angular.json`:

```
"schematics": {
      "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
}
```