# Adding Angular CLI support to old Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a project that was created a long time back without using Angular CLI tools.  Recently, I've been trying to look at improving load performance within my app, and I wanted to see if I can use the optimization tools under CLI, so I installed it with npm.  When trying to run the command "ng build" I get the following error: `The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.`

Does Angular CLI require the app to be created under the tool?  I've been using `package.json` to define my angular app, but I see mentions of using `angular.json` for cli, do I need to modify the `package.json` file?  Is there a way I can support the CLI module under my app?

Comment: Also see [**How to migrate an Angular Application that was not created with the Angular CLI**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57556717/1164465)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method is to use Angular CLI to create a brand new application by running `ng new your-app-name`. Migrate your packages over to the newly generated package.json file. Delete the app module that was generated and use your existing app module.

Comment: Yeah, I've been researching that and it looks like my only go-to solution at the moment.  Unfortunately, I created this app when I was new to Angular, so there are a lot of configuration steps I need